# Is this a correct representation of how SAML authentication with OneLogin is meant to work

Tags: saml, onelogin

I hate to ask such a non-concrete question, but after reading a ton of [OneLogin docs](https://developers.onelogin.com/), asking on their forums to no response, and asking several developer communities, I'm still very sketchy on the intended workflow. My understanding is that it's similar to OAuth but with claims embedded in SAML xml documents.

The below diagram is of my understanding of the workflow (the topmost node says "Get Resource"). Is this correct?

[image: OneLogin workflow understanding]

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overcomplicating it. The Identity Provider will send a request that you will validate. This is the same for all IDps (OneLogin, Okta, Ping Identity,...). If the request it validated, you grant the user access to the app leveraging the nameid which most of the times is agreed to be an email. If it doesn't you can present a message telling them as much info as you want why the request failed plus a link for them to return to their app. This may be or not possible depending on what caused the validation to fail. OneLogin toolkits will save you a lot of time when you want to set up your app as Service Provider.

Comment: well yes, that works for a single request, but you're not doing that on *every* request since that would be...well pretty insane. So as far as I understand either the user or the server session keeps around a copy of their token and claims and you check authorization off of *those*. But then what happens when the user is disabled at the IDP, how does the app find out and invalidate that local copy? What's stopping the user from forging the claims that are passed to the identity provider to begin with?

Comment: SAML doesn't really do session management - But if you'd like you can set a short session timeout on your servers so it frequently (but not too frequently!) checks with the Identity provider to make sure the user is still allowed access. In order to do this, you need to look up how to do Service Provider initiated SAML.

Beyond that SAML, assertions are signed/encrypted with a secret key to prevent tampering / playback.